# In Java, why dont I need to import RuntimeException to use it?

Tags: java, import, ioexception, runtimeexception

If I try to use IOException without the fully qualified name and without importing, I get a compilation error. But it doesn't happen when I do the same with, say, RuntimeException or Exception.
Why is that?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Classes from package `java.lang.` need not be imported. It's not just RuntimeException, but also stuff like Object and String.